# No Credit card option with paypal payment method

Tags: php, paypal, web, commerce

I am trying to learn integrating paypal for shopping checkouts. I have created a website with custom cart. Now I have added the paypal integration code after watching this http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDbTqeSUrQY&feature=relmfu

It works but only problem is when I try it out with sandbox, or real account from buyers perspective I can't use credit card i.e i need paypal account to perform. I have no idea whether I need to change the code or change settings in paypal. I tried going through their documents nothing is mention, it says i can accept credit card payments in express and standard accounts, but how?

The code I used

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="abhishek.salian.85@gmail.com">
<?php if($_SESSION['cart']) { $total = 0;$i=0;
foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $product_id => $quantity) {
$product_details = get_product_details($product_id);
$row_cost = $product_details[product_price] * $quantity;
$total = $total + $row_cost; $x=$i+1; ?>
<input type="hidden" name="item_name_<?php echo $x; ?>" value="<?php echo $product_details[product_title]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="quantity_<?php echo $x; ?>" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['cart'][product_id]; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_<?php echo $x; ?>" value="<?php echo $product_details[product_price]; ?>">
<?php $product_id_array = $product_details[product_id]."-".$_SESSION['cart'][product_id].",";$i++; } } ?>
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $product_id_array; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="<?php echo WEBSITE.'paypal/ipn.php'; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="<?php echo WEBSITE.'products/thank_you'; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Retun to Flash Shop">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="<?php echo WEBSITE.'products/cancel'; ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="AU">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!"></form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's a setting in your seller account - not something you pass in with the form.

Under Profile, fund the "Website Payment Preferences" link and then look for the "PayPal Account Optional" section.  Choose "On" and save your settings.

Comment: Please accept this answer, or indicate why this solution did not work for you. Thanks.